# Why are new CPT posts already populated

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, divi

Issue: When adding new CPT or editing existing the post content is being overwritten. i.e. for all CPT the visible content is the same

Environment: WordPressv6, Divi Theme Builder, CPT-UI, ACF

1. Added CPT
2. Created archive template for CPT - Divi Theme builder
3. Added some CPT posts

Now, when I add a new post the last post content appears when I 'view' a new one.
Also, all the posts have the same content. (ie. first, second etc to the current one that was saved)

Is this CPT or Divi issue?

Comment: i assume that possibly the template always gets a specific post on the CPTs single post page. Instead of checking which post is actually requested, and using that. Can't really explain this a lot different on my side.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation this is the conclusion:

A custom template is designed in Divi as a container. The template that is designed is set for ALL custom post types.
When creating a new Post the template is loaded (as Divi). Any changes to this are saved to the original template.
This also overwrites the other posts with the same content.

From what I've deduced: Custom designed templates are to create containers for consistent static or dynamic content. They (the posts themselves) should not be 'edited' with Divi.

The way around this is to remove the CPT template and use standard DIVI editor for each post. CLONING appears to be the best approach for this for anyone who comes across this issue.

So: Templates used for consistent static content for ALL CPT or containers holding dynamic content in ACF or elsewhere.
Cloning posts allows posts elements to be re-used and individually styled.